# No option to submit and retrieve SAP UI5 application in ABAP Repository

Tags: eclipse, sapui5, abap

I got an issue regarding submitting and retrieving SAP UI5 applications. Usually I would create my UI5 project and submit it by right clicking on project and then TEAMS->Share-> then I share my project to ABAP repository.

Unfortunately Eclipse won't show me any connections and it shows when I resize the window as showing in first two images(image: error1 and error2).

and no repositories are show in eclipse as well(image : error3)

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug that I am experiencing as well. And to the other answer, no that does not mean there are No Repositories in the ABAP system. This is being caused by a bug in Eclipse/UI5 that creates these inconsistencies. I have connected to the UI5 Repository fine previously and until this bug started showing up, I get the same issues as depicted above where you start seeing ADT issues, no UI5 repositories shown, the missing connections window etc....

FYI - I also have colleagues using the same version of Eclipse, that are able to Team share to the same SAP back end system fine and others that have this issue.

I have an SAP Incident out for this for over a week with no response from SAP yet. I will update if I indeed get some resolution from SAP on this matter.

**Update**

SAP has issued a fix as of yesterday, as detailed in OSS Note 2941289.
If you do a "Check for Updates" in Eclipse, you will now see a new version of SAPUI5 Tools ver. 1.71.1

I have validated and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

It means no UI5 repository is created in your ABAP system.

Resize the last windows to the fullscreen and you will get "Create BSP app" in the bottom

[image]

then you choose the package and [create BSP app](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/c9/4f13fd242f40beb64e08fc62c494e7/content.htm?no_cache=true) where your UI5 app will be stored in repository.

Comment: Yes I have done this as well and gave my package but still I'm unable to submit my project. And Im getting the same error as yours "ADT Discovery".how can I fix this?

Comment: it is a separate question, in my system it is the problem of connectivity, because my system behind the SAP router and VPN, your error may be different (ADT misconfig or whatever), follow my question [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13079684/error-when-getting-results-unable-to-initialize-ad.html), maybe there will be helpful answers to you

Comment: yes you are right but my question was about no repositories were showing even resizing you can see that in last image.most you people are facing this same issue but no one has solved this yet. Even the link you shared there's no any answer there. Everyone is referring SAP Note but its related to WEBIDE not eclipse.

Comment: It works with SAP Router and VPN as well. My other team members are using this same tool with VPN and router.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. But now it got resolved.
No repositories are shown in the screen that is because of ui5 tools issue.
i reinstalled all the abap and ui5 tools of 2019-11 version because sap stopped it support for latest ui5 tools. so, any update you did may cause this issue.